# Robot Framework Adding Keywords

Tags: java, python, annotations, keyword, robotframework

I am having an issue with picking up custom keywords for Java using the [Annotation Library](https://github.com/robotframework/JavalibCore/wiki/AnnotationLibrary). The issue I'm facing is that I am getting the following error when executing with jybot:

Imported library 'org.robotframework.javalib.library.ClassPathLibrary' contains no keywords

Imported library 'org.robotframework.javalib.library.AnnotationLibrary' contains no keywords

No keyword with name 'Create an Empty Stack' found
Jybot command used: jybot example.txt.Below is the actual test case and the libraries that are called for this test case:

```
*** Settings ***
Library    org.robotframework.javalib.library.ClassPathLibrary     org/robotframework/example/keyword/**.class
Library    org.robotframework.javalib.library.AnnotationLibrary    org/robotframework/example/keyword/**.class


*** Test Cases ***

Stack Example
      Create an Empty Stack
      Add an Element Java
      Add an Element C++
      Remove last Element
      The last Element should be
```

Below is the library written to incorporate the keyword written to incorporate the Stack keywords:

```
package org.robotframework.example.keyword;

import org.robotframework.javalib.annotation.RobotKeyword;
import org.robotframework.javalib.annotation.RobotKeywords;
import org.robotframework.javalib.library.AnnotationLibrary;

/**
 * 
 */

    /**
     * 
     */
    @RobotKeywords

    public class StackKeyword extends AnnotationLibrary {
        /** This means the same instance of this class is used throughout
         *  the lifecycle of a Robot Framework test execution.
         */
        public static final String ROBOT_LIBRARY_SCOPE = "GLOBAL";

        public StackKeyword() {
            super("org/robotframework/example/keyword/**/*.class");
        }
        //</editor-fold>
        /** The Functionality to be tested */
        private java.util.Stack<String> testStack;

        /**
         * Keyword-method to create an empty stack.
         */
        @RobotKeyword
        public void createAnEmptyStack() {
            testStack = new java.util.Stack<String>();
        }


        /**
         * Keyword-method to add an element to the stack.
         * @param element The element
         */
        @RobotKeyword
        public void addAnElement(String element) {
            testStack.push(element);
        }

        /**
         * Keyword-method to remove the last element from the stack.
         */
        @RobotKeyword
        public void removeLastElement() {
            testStack.pop();
        }

        /**
         * Keyword-method to search for an element position.
         * @param element The element
         * @param pos The expected position
         */
        @RobotKeyword
        public void elementShouldBeAtPosition(String element, int pos)
                throws Exception {
            if (testStack.search(element) != pos) {
                throw new Exception("Wrong position: " + testStack.search(element));
            }
        }

        /**
         * Keyword-method to check the last element in the stack.
         * @param result Expected resulting element
         */
        @RobotKeyword
        public void theLastElementShouldBe(String result) throws Exception {
            String element = testStack.pop();
            if (!result.equals(element)) {
                throw new Exception("Wrong element: " + element);
            }
        }



    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a class extends `AnnotationLibrary` and implement default constructor.

```
public class DemoLibrary extends AnnotationLibrary {

    public DemoLibrary () {
        super("org/robotframework/example/**/*.class");
    }
}
```

Put your keywords class under package `org.robotframework.example.keywords`

In example.txt file put only;

```
Library           org.robotframework.example.DemoLibrary
```

Be sure that you have DemoLibrary at that path.